# Examine JSON populating Struts autocompleter

Tags: json, autocomplete, struts2

I have a select box populated by JSON using a Struts autocompleter:

```
<sj:autocompleter 
    id="stop" 
    name="stopId"
    href="%{stopsUrl}" 
    list="stops" 
    listValue="stopName" 
    listKey="stopId" 
    autocomplete="true"
    loadMinimumCount="2"
    delay="200"
    tabindex="1"
    onSelectTopics="onStopSelected"
/>
```

This makes an Ajax request to `stopsUrl` that returns a list of `stops` objects each of which has a `stopId` and a `stopName` as well as a `stopType`.
I need to save the `stopType` somewhere (I guess by using JQuery `data` function), and then when the user selects a stop, the `onStopSelected` function will retrieve the `stopType` and do something with it.

So I think I'll need to examine the data in the JSON response to get the `stopType` for each stop. But how can I access this? Which event do I need to subscribe to? Is it possible using Struts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there's a better way, but I've done it like this.

I've deleted the line `onSelectTopics="onStopSelected"` that was in the question, and instead use (old) jQuery to read the JSON in the `autocompleteopen` event:

```
$( "#stop_widget" ).live( "autocompleteopen", function() {
    var stops = $(this).data("autocomplete").response.caller.arguments[0].stops;
    var stopTypes = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < stops.length; i++) {
        stopTypes[stops[i].stopId] = stops[i].stopType;
    }
    $("#stop").data("stopTypes", stopTypes);
});
```

Then in the `autocompleteselect` event, I can access the `stopType`:

```
$("#stop_widget").bind( "autocompleteselect", function(event,data){
    var selectedStopId = data.item.key;
    var stopTypes = $("#stop").data("stopTypes");
    var selectedStopType = stopTypes[selectedStopId];
    // do something with the selectedStopType
});
```